# Squidguard + LDAP (Active Directory) not working

Tags: ldap, squid

I've been trying to configure a squid with squidguard and MS AD. I've successfuly linked my squid with my AD so far, but now, I want to link my squidguard with the active directory.

I've followed multiple tutorial, but i'm stuck with the same problem : when I launch squid, I have

```
2013-09-11 16:45:21 [6519] New setting: dbhome: /var/lib/squidguard/db
2013-09-11 16:45:21 [6519] New setting: logdir: /var/log/squid
2013-09-11 16:45:21 [6519] syntax error in configfile /etc/squid3/squidGuard.conf line 4
2013-09-11 16:45:21 [6519] Going into emergency mode
```

This is the error I get with the squidGuard 1.4 that I compiled with the --with-ldap=yes option.

Here's my squidGuard.conf file :

```
ldapbinddn CN="Acces AD",OU=Utilisateurs,DC=company,DC=local
ldapbindpass mypassword
ldapcachetime 60

src admin {
 ldapusersearch ldap://192.168.20.1:389/dc=company,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(memberof=CN=mygroup%2cOU=Users%2cDC=company%2cDC=local)(sAMAccountName=%s))
}
```

It seems that my squidGuard build is not compiled with LDAP support, but I did specified the option when I ran the compile script.
I searched pretty much everything I could think of in google, but it did not solve my problem, so I was hoping that I may find some enlightenment here.

EDIT :

I installed the debian squidGuard package, and I have some new things in my squidGuard.log :

```
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7003] New setting: ldapcachetime: 60
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7003] syntax error in configfile /etc/squid3/squidGuard.conf line 9
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7003] Going into emergency mode
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] New setting: dbhome: /var/lib/squidguard/db
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] New setting: logdir: /var/log/squid
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] New setting: ldapbinddn: CN="Acces AD",OU=Utilisateurs,DC=company,DC=local
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] New setting: ldapbindpass: mypassword
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] New setting: ldapcachetime: 60
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] syntax error in configfile /etc/squid3/squidGuard.conf line 9
2013-09-11 17:44:07 [7004] Going into emergency mode
```

Comment: Why don't you match the user that logs in the internet with a txt on you own squid? I use some rules on my squid.conf that when someone access it, it'll only access the youtube, for exemple, if it has added to a file on a txt on var/lib/squidguard/db/datingpress/gpress.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but generally when i'm using squidGuard, I found that having it search LDAP was relatively slow, and it can already use the authenticated user name directly from Squid itself, I basically just have a text file with the list of users that need special privileges.

e.g.

```
...
src userGroup1{
    userlist /etc/squid/userGroup1.txt
}
...
acl{
    userGroup1 {
       pass good whitelist graylist !bad !malware any
    }
    default {
       pass good whitelist !bad !malware any
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `ldapbinddn CN="Acces AD",OU=Utilisateurs,DC=company,DC=local` to

```
ldapbinddn "CN=Acces AD,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=company,DC=local"
```

Comment: I changed the line to match yours, but I still have the same error. The line 9 in my config file matches the `ldapusersearch ldap://192.168.20.1:389/dc=company,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(memberof=CN=mygroup%2cOU=Users%2cDC=company%2cDC=local)(sAMAccountName=%s))` line. 
Maybe it is malformed ? Is there any way to make squidGuard more verbose ?

Comment: @valentin, you just specify the bind DN as is, no need to add any quotes.